# Find tables related to Primary Key or Foreign Key from big database

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have more than 3500 tables where it is very hard to find the relationship between those tables. I am using 11g very old version which as not support to data modelling. Any please advise me how to find the relational tables based on Primary and Foreign key or creating data modelling in Oracle SQL Developer version 1.1.3 (with 11g).

Comment: Are you asking how to create primary and foreign keys from the Oracle user interface or from actual code from an SQL script?

Comment: why are you using SQL Developer version 1? Go to oracle.com/sqldeveloper and download the latest version of SQL Developer Data Modeler, connect to your DB, and reverse engineer your 3500 tables schema

Comment: Thank you Max and Jeff Smith.. Jeff, I have seen all videos and gone through the your website, It was lot helpful in my career and work. Currently where I am working they dont have any latest version ratherthan version 1. even the company is using Oracle 11g. Max: my question is finding related tables from any single table based on primary and foreign key relationship. Thank you